# How to group one attribute based on another attribute in mdx

Tags: group-by, sql-server-2012, mdx

I want to get a hierarchical output from a `mdx` query. From the following query it gives me the output in a flat manner. Like for all the corporation in gives the result for 'All',then it starts giving result for 'Pharmacy' and so on.

[image]

But I want it like the following for each corporation.

[image]

Here is the `mdx` query that I have written:

```
 WITH 
  SET Last36Months AS 
    LastPeriods
    (36
     ,[Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1]
    ) 
  SET LatestMonth AS 
    {
      //  [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1].lag(24),
      //  [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1].lag(12),
      [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1]
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[UnitSales] AS 
    (
      Last36Months
     ,[Measures].[SALES UNITS (000)]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ValueSales] AS 
    (
      Last36Months
     ,[Measures].[SALES VALUES (000)]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    (
      LatestMonth
     ,[Measures].[SALES VALUES (000)]
    )
   ,(
      LatestMonth
     ,[Measures].[SALES UNITS (000)]
    )
  } ON 0
 ,{
    Order
    (
        NonEmpty
        (
          (
            [CHANNEL].[Channel].[All]
           ,[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].&[1]
           ,[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].MEMBERS
          )
        )
      + 
        NonEmpty
        (
          (
            Descendants
            (
              [CHANNEL].[Channel].[All]
             ,1
            )
           ,[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].&[1]
           ,[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].MEMBERS
          )
        )
     ,[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].Name
     ,bdesc
    )
  } ON 1
FROM [PharmaTrend Monthly Stand Reg];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a custom set - you can stick with your original idea of including the `ORDER` inside the `SELECT`:

```
WITH 
  SET Last36Months AS 
    LastPeriods
    (36
     ,[Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1]
    ) 
  SET LatestMonth AS 
    {
      //  [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1].lag(24),
      //  [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1].lag(12),
      [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1]
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[UnitSales] AS 
    (
      Last36Months
     ,[Measures].[SALES UNITS (000)]
    ) 
  MEMBER [Measures].[ValueSales] AS 
    (
      Last36Months
     ,[Measures].[SALES VALUES (000)]
    )   
SELECT 
  {
    (
      LatestMonth
     ,[Measures].[SALES VALUES (000)]
    )
   ,(
      LatestMonth
     ,[Measures].[SALES UNITS (000)]
    )
  } ON 0
 ,Order
    (
        NonEmpty
        (
          (
            [CHANNEL].[Channel].[All]
           ,[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].&[1]
           ,[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].MEMBERS
          )
        )
      + 
        NonEmpty
        (
          (
            Descendants
            (
              [CHANNEL].[Channel].[All]
             ,1
            )
           ,[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].&[1]
           ,[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].MEMBERS
          )
        )
     ,[CORPORATION].[Corporation].CurrentMember.MemberValue 
     ,bdesc
    )  ON 1
FROM [PharmaTrend Monthly Stand Reg];
```

Comment: You don't have a scope set for `[CORPORATION].[Corporation]`. Are you sure `[CORPORATION].[Corporation].CurrentMember` won't be same as `[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[All]`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to sort by the member names from `[CORPORATION].[Corporation]` hierarchy.

In that case, below should work:

```
with set Last36Months as 
LASTPERIODS(36, [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1])

Set LatestMonth as
{

//  [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1].lag(24),
//  [Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1].lag(12),
[Period JNJ].[Period Type-Year-Period].[Periods].&[MTH1]

}

member [Measures].[UnitSales] as
(Last36Months,[Measures].[SALES UNITS (000)])

member [Measures].[ValueSales] as 
(Last36Months,[Measures].[SALES VALUES (000)])


member [Measures].CorporationName as 
[CORPORATION].[Corporation].currentmember.membervalue

set OrderedSet as
order(
(
nonempty(([CHANNEL].[Channel].[All],[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].&[1],     [CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].members))+
nonempty((descendants([CHANNEL].[Channel].[All],1),[MARKET BASE].[Market Base].&[1],[CORPORATION].[Corporation].[Corporation].members))
)
,[Measures].CorporationName
,bdesc)


select 
{  
(LatestMonth,[Measures].[SALES VALUES (000)]),
(LatestMonth,[Measures].[SALES UNITS (000)])
} on 0,
OrderedSet on 1
from [PharmaTrend Monthly Stand Reg]
```

Comment: @sourav - you have 4 arguments in your ORDER function.